# Given $f \in L^p$ and $g \in L^q$, show $f*g$ uniformly continuous, and...

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Given $f \in L^p$ and $g \in L^q$, I want to that their convolution $f*g$ is uniformly continuous.  I further want to show that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f*g(x) = \lim_{x\to -\infty} f*g(x) = 0$.

I've seen some explanations involving approximation and density arguments, which I don't really understand, as we haven't covered that material yet.  So, I assume that means I must be able to answer this question without them?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: For the former question, one needs only the fact that continuous function with compact support is dense in $L^{p}$, $1\leq p<\infty$. Are you allowed to use this one? If not, then I don't how to do it as well.

Answer (score 1):

By H$\ddot{\mathrm{o}}$lder's Inequality,
\begin{align*}
|f\ast g(x)-f\ast g(y)|&=\left|\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(t)(g(x-t)-g(y-t))\,\mathrm{d}t\right|\\
&\leq \|f\|_{p}\|g(x-\cdot)-g(y-\cdot)\|_{q}\\
&= \|f\|_{p}\|g-g(\cdot-(x-y))\|_{q},
\end{align*}
and by the continuity of the translation operator $T_{a}:L^{q}\rightarrow L^{q},$ $T_{a}g=g(\cdot-a)$, the right hand side goes to zero as $|x-y|\rightarrow0,$ with the rate depending only on $x-y$ (and not the specific values of $x$ and $y$), which gives the desired uniform continuity.

Observe that since $f\in L^{p},$ $g\in L^{q},$ given $\varepsilon>0,$ there is some positive number $M_{f}$ such that $\int_{\{|x|>M_{f}\}}|f(x)|^{p}\mathrm{d}x<\varepsilon,$ and similarly there is a $M_{g}$ with the corresponding property for $g.$ Let $M=\max\{M_{f},M_{g}\}.$ Then letting $\chi(x)$ be the indicator function for the interval $[-M,M]$, when $|x|>2M,$ noting that $\chi(t)\chi(x-t)\equiv 0$,
\begin{align*}
|f\ast g(x)|&=\left|\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(t)g(x-t)\mathrm{d}t\right|\\
&=\left|\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(t)(\chi(t)+(1-\chi)(t))g(x-t)(\chi(x-t)+(1-\chi)(x-t))\mathrm{d}t\right|\\&\leq\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f(t)g(x-t)|(\chi(t)(1-\chi)(x-t)+(1-\chi)(t)\chi(x-t)+(1-\chi)(t)(1-\chi)(x-t))\mathrm{d}t.
\end{align*}
Since $f\chi, f(1-\chi)\in L^{p},$ and $g\chi,g(1-\chi)\in L^{q},$ we may apply H$\ddot{\mathrm{o}}$lder's Inequality to each of these three pieces to obtain (for $|x|>2M$): \begin{align*}|f\ast g(x)|&\leq \|f\chi\|_{p}\|g(1-\chi)\|_{q}+\|f(1-\chi)\|_{p}\|g\chi\|_{q}+\|f(1-\chi)\|_{p}\|g(1-\chi)\|_{q}\\&\leq \|f\|_{p}\sqrt[q]{\varepsilon}+\sqrt[p]{\varepsilon}\|g\|_{q}+\sqrt[p]{\varepsilon}\sqrt[q]{\varepsilon},
\end{align*}
where we used the definition of $M$ in the last inequality. This is sufficient to prove that $f\ast g(x)\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow\pm\infty.$

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{Lemma 1.}\textit{ $C_c(\mathbb{R})$ is dense in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$}$.

$\textit{Proof.}$. You say you are not familiar with this, but I will sketch a proof. First, if $f \in L^p$, then off some compact set, the integral of $|f|^p$ will be negligible. Then, using simple function approximations to $f$ on our compact set, we see that it suffices to show that a simple function can be approximated in $L^p$, and by linearity, just a characteristic function. So take $f \equiv \chi_A$ where $0<m(A) <\infty$ and $A$ has compact closure. Then take $K \subset A \subset G$, with $K$ closed and $G$ open, such that $m(A\setminus K)< \displaystyle \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and likewise $m(G\setminus A)< \displaystyle \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. 
$$g(x) = \frac{d(x,K^c)}{d(x,K^c) + d(x,A)},$$
where $d$ is the distance function. Then $g$ differs from $f$ on a set of measure less than $\displaystyle \frac\epsilon2$ as you can check, and is continuous.

$\textbf{Lemma 2.}\textit{ Let $f_h(x) = f(x+h)$. If $f \in L^p$, then $\|f_h - f\|_p \to 0$ as $h \to 0$.}$

$\textit{Proof.}$ For $\epsilon>0$ take $g \in C_c(\mathbb{R})$ with $\|g-f\|_p <\epsilon$. Then $g$ is uniformly continuous, so we have 
$$\|f_h - f\|_p \le \|f_h - g_h\|_p + \|g_h - g\|_p + \|g- f\|_p < \epsilon + \|g_h - g\|_p +\epsilon.$$
By continuity the middle term goes to zero as $h \to 0$. This concludes the lemma. $\blacksquare$

Now for the proof, fix $x$ and see
$$|f\ast g(x+h) - f\ast g (x)| = \left|\left(f(x+h-y) - f(x-y)\right)g(y) \ dy\right|$$
$$\le \int\left|f(x+h-y) - f(x-y)\right||g(y)| \ dy \le \|f_{h-y} - f_{-y}\|_p \|g\|_q \to 0$$
by the lemma, since $f_{-y} \in L^p$ by translation invariance and $f_{h-y}$ is just the shift by $h$ of $f_{-y}$. Then the lemma tells us we have convergence to zero. We have used Holder's, and the fact that $f \in L^p$ and $g \in L^q$. We immediately have uniform continuity, since $|f\ast g (x+h) - f\ast g(x)|$ is bounded by something (which tends to $0$) that only depends on $h$.

To see that $f\ast g(x) \to 0$ as $|x|\to \infty$: given $\epsilon>0$ take $R$ large such that $\displaystyle \|f\chi_{B(0,R)^c}\|_p <\epsilon$ and likewise $\|g\chi_{B(0,R)^c}\|_q <\epsilon$. We can do this because $f\in L^p$ and $g\in L^q$, so by dominated convergence $g\chi_{B(0,R)} \stackrel{L^q}\mapsto g$, and likewise, $f\chi_{B(0,R)} \stackrel{L^q}\mapsto f$. Now, take $|x|>2R$ and suppose without loss of generality that $x>0$. Then 
$$|f\ast g(x)| = \left|\int_\mathbb{R} f(x-y)g(y) \ dy \right| \le \int_\mathbb{R} |f(x-y)||g(y)| \ dy$$
$$= \int_{B(0,R)^c} |f(x-y)||g(y)| \ dy + \int_{-R}^R |f(x-y)||g(y)| \ dy \le \|g\chi_{B(0,R)^c}\|_q \|f\|_p + \int_{x-R}^{x+R}|f(u)||g(x-u)|\ du$$
$$<\epsilon \|f\|_p + \int_{R}^{x+R} |f(u)||g(x-u)| \ du \le \epsilon \|f\|_p + \|f\chi_{B(0,R)^c}\|_p\|g\|_q < \epsilon(\|f\|_p + \|g\|_q).$$
We have used Holder's several times, as well as change of variables. This shows that $|f\ast g(x)| \to 0$ as $|x|\to \infty$, as desired.